# Google Sheets: How to customize the column order in QUERY pivot?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a solution to get the data from columns A, B, C and pivot it as shown in the screenshot. I am using the dropdown in cell F1 for switching the `fulfilled` column in the pivot with the `requested` column. The issue with the `QUERY` function is that, when I switch between the above two options, the column order also changes.

Is there a way to fix `orders` in column G only?

P.S.: Additionally, can I filter out the value `orders` from the dropdown without creating a secondary list? The dropdown is a simple data validation with specified range as B2:B.

```
=QUERY(A2:C10,"SELECT A, SUM(C) WHERE B MATCHES '(orders|"& F1 &")'GROUP BY A PIVOT B")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion:

You can try this two QUERY formula to fix `orders` in column G only.

```
={QUERY(A2:C10,"SELECT A, SUM(C) WHERE B MATCHES '("& F1 &")'GROUP BY A PIVOT B"),QUERY(A2:C10,"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE B='orders' GROUP BY A LABEL SUM(C) 'orders'")}
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en